# Return Functions from parallel execution of module

Tags: programming, function-construction, parallelization

I wrote a module which numerically solves an ODE using `NDSolve`. The result from this is e.g. either `InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1000.}},<>][t]` or `InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1000.}},<>][t$1062]`, depending whether the independent varialbe `t` is global or local in the module.

So far, I didn't care that it is global and everything worked fine. As this is imho is a source of upcoming trouble, I would like to switch to the local variable-version. As therefore I can't use a replacement rule like `InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1000.}},<>][t] /. t->3` to extract single values or to plot the function any more, I tried to wrap it into a function as the following minimal example demonstrates.

```
compute[] := Module[{res, f},
   points = Table[{x, x}, {x, 0, 10}];
   res = Interpolation[points];
   f[x_] := res[x];
   f
];
```

Using this code works fine.

```
In[109]:= ex = compute[];
          ex[3]
Out[110]= 3
```

I now want to run this computation with different parameters so I put it into a `ParallelTable`. The resulting list then does not contain the correct functions anymore but only their symbols.

```
In[111]:= a = ParallelTable[compute[], {i, 0, 100}];
          a[[1]][3]

Out[112]= f$1870[3]
```

Note that this works perfectly when `ParallelTable` is replace by a normal `Table`.

Can you explain to me why this happens? Has this something to do with the definitions of the functions "living" on the sub-kernels and not being passed back to the main kernel?

**Edit**

Another aspect of the problem, a solution to which would help me too, is the following.
If I multiply the `InterpolatingFunction` by a number and try to then extract values from it, it doesn't work as I would expect. Using the above example and assuming tha `res` is returned (indicated by the use of `res` in the following).

```
In[150]:= fcn=5*res;
          fcn[3]

Out[151]= (5 InterpolatingFunction[{{0,10}},<>])[3]
```

Is there maybe a workaround for this?

Comment: Yes, it does. The symbol `f$1870` has no definition associated with it in the master kernel.  You could avoid this problem if `compute[]` would return `res` rather than `f`.

Comment: But then I'm stuck with the problem of using the result. If `t` is global, I can use the replacement rule. If not, I don't see another way to use it. Do you know if there is a way to copy the definition to the master kernel?

Comment: Are you aware that `NDSolve[]` can be made to output a *pure function*, which would seem to be more convenient for your applications? Witness, for instance, `f = y /. First @ NDSolve[{y''[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 3}]`

Comment: @J.M. That's what I tried to describe in the edit of the question. Using your solution has (at least at my machine) the problem that I can't modify the function by multiplying something, e.g. `a = 3*f; a[3]` won't return a number because it doesn't evaluate the InterpolatingFunction then.

Comment: So, try `a = Composition[3 # &, f]`...

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you!
PS: If you put your comment in an answer, I could mark it as solved.